# Batch alter existing PDF files

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat, mailmerge

I have 1700 PDF datasheets that contain a set of text and image boxes. The underlying template of each datasheet is the same, but the contents of the boxes vary. I'd like to find a program that lets me take the modified text box contents (summarized in an excel table) and repopulate the original sheets.

I have extracted the information from the text boxes using the "Merge Data files into an excel file" under the Prepare Form tool in Adobe DC and have used a variety of =Substitute functions in excel to change the contents of the text boxes to what I want. What I would like to do now is use a program to go back to the original .PDF and overwrite the original fields. I would just run a mail merge on this normally, but I don't have access to the images anymore so the image boxes would be blank.

Alternatively I've considered using something like Pulover Macro Creator to step through the excel list and paste in the contents into every sheet, but I'm hoping that there's an existing piece of software to do this.

Comment: If you did not mind the existing content being left behind, you could use XSL FO technology to stamp white box and then text over the existing one, with the old PDF as a background image.

Comment: @Kevin Brown don't think this would look acceptable for the client. The background of the original text box is a transparent grid image so I can't even overlay with a matching colour.